# OLAP Cube column properties values

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, dax, olap

I have an olap cube and I'm trying to get a data for reporting automation in PowerBI. I have problem with one of column what value is only viewed as a properties :

MDX hierarchy example:

```
[Sales Order].[SALES ORDER].[SALES ORDER].Properties("Customer Note")
```

I'm trying to write an mdx query to get a values of this table

My code:

```
SELECT
    [Sales Order].[SALES ORDER].[SALES ORDER].Properties('Customer Note') ON ROWS, 
    [Customer].[Customer ID] ON COLUMNS
FROM
    [MyCube]
```

But I'm getting an error all the time, any idea? I'm 1st time have ever meet with only properties values.

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing that into a custom measure in A WITH clause:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures]·[X] AS
[Sales Order].[SALES ORDER].[SALES ORDER].Properties('Customer Note')
SELECT
   [Measures]·[X]  ON 0, 
    [Customer].[Customer ID] ON 1
FROM
    [MyCube]
```